# ES6 Extending BaseClass without calling constructor and when I am trying to call a method in my subclass throwing error

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

Extending BaseClass without calling constructor and when I am trying to call a method in my subclass throwing error

```
class BaseClass {
    constructor(cfg) {

    // Transfer all properties to class object
    Object.assign(this, cfg);

    if(this.el instanceof HTMLElement === false) {
        return;
    }
    this.setup(); 
}

setup() {
    this.isSetup = true;
}
```

}

Do I need to call constructor to access this object in current class ?

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
   setup() {
    // Calling super
    super.setup();

    this.show(); **// this.show is not a function**
   }
   show = () => {
     console.log('called');
   }
}
```

Comment: [Unless I'm missing something, the example code provided here seems to work fine](https://repl.it/@Kingdaro/MeatyIndigoRadius)

Comment: Don't call methods from the constructor, only initialise fields. And never call overidable methods on instances that might not yet have been completely initialised!

Comment: @kingdaro You missed arrow function.